# Unable to test docusign in SOAPUI

Tags: docusignapi

I ma trying to test docusign REST API using soapui. But it throwing an error

{
   "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
   "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}

I have an demo account and integration key setup. Please help.

Thanks
Bharat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are specifying the wrong integrator Key.

If you are using the [legacy authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) Header, make sure you are passing it as follows.

```
<DocuSignCredentials>
 <Username>developer@example.com</Username>
 <Password>S3cre+p455w0Rd</Password>
 <IntegratorKey>your integrator key</IntegratorKey>
</DocuSignCredentials>'
```

If you are using [oAuth](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html). Look at this documentation.

Comment: Hi Dawg, Thank you. I am trying something like below in SOAPUI. I am new to soapui , I might be missing something. But on docusign i set the correct integration key.Thanks

Comment: Not getting how to add an attachment here

Comment: Now its throwing an different error {
   "errorCode": "PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED",
   "message": "The validation of the PDF file failed."
}

Comment: Below is th request "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "contract.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "test"
    }],

Comment: You have to send a base64 encoded document for it to work. "test" is not base 64 encoded

Comment: Could you please give an example like how to send this document parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much and its working.. I will figure out how to send PDF

Answer (score 0):

Using Json via Rest API at `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2` , always remember to include below code for all your requests to DocuSign.

```
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + _username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + _password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + _integratorKey + "\"}";

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);

req.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
```